# Can I add javascript inside the body tag to ADF application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oracle-adf

`af:resource` automatically adds the item to the `head` tag. I would like to load AngularJS just before the closing of the body tag. How can I do this in ADF?

I tried referencing "xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" and `<h:outputScript>` but this did not work for me. Any ideas how I can load the javascript properly?

I need to do it this way because I don't like the ADF implementation but unfortunately the client uses this framework so I have to find ways to work around it.

Code:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
      xmlns:pe="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/pageeditor"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:cust="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/customizable" 
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt">
```

inside the jspx

```
 <af:panelGroupLayout id="footer" layout="vertical">
            <af:group id="footerGroup">



                 <h:outputScript name="js/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"/>

            </af:group>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
```

The actual output in the jdeveloper log pane

```
Error(241,23):  This tag is not recognized.
```

Comment: So you are going to develop a webapp using AngularJS in ADF?

Comment: yes that's the plan. I have most of it working. Basically just working around ADF. I was brought on late in the project and am not familiar with ADF.

Comment: Since you are not using any ADF stuff, just use plain HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

put your AngularJS code inside   `<f:verbatim>`  tag

-- Peddi